# Issue in accessing google storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, storage, google-cloud-sdk

I am using two GCP accounts, I setup a google cloud sdk and accessed GS bucket from account 1.  Now I would like to access another GS bucket which is mapped to another account and when I run the command

```
client.get_bucket(bucket)
```

It says 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/agencyq-bucket?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false:  does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: Provide details on how you are authorizing your code (ADC, service account). Have you reviewed the Google Cloud documentation for Identity and Access Management and how to assign roles to IAM members plus how to add IAM members to accounts?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had exported the json file path in environment variables even then it didn't work. Then I explicitly used json file path in the code and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 opitions we can take.
One is to add `storage.buckets.get` access by adding `Storage Legacy Bucket Reader` Role.
(Or add another role that has `storage.buckets.get` ).

The other is to change the code as follows:

```
# Don't Use get_bucket() because it needs storage.buckets.get
# Use client.bucket() Insted.
# client.get_bucket(bucket)
your_bucket = client.bucket(bucket)

# then use bucket
your_blob = your_bucket.blob( known_blob_path)
your_blob.download_to_filename(known_object_path)
```